# c# windows application Live Charts x axis date forma

Tags: c#, .net, livecharts

Hello everyone i working in project that convert data (date and value) to graphic curve .
i have problem with x axis the value of date printing in double format , i want this values showing like this format 14:12:35

```
var gradientBrush = new LinearGradientBrush
                 {
                     StartPoint = new System.Windows.Point(0, 0),
                     EndPoint = new System.Windows.Point(0, 1)
                 };
                 gradientBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(33, 148, 241), 0.2));
                 gradientBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Transparent, 1));


                 cartesianChart1.Series.Add(new LineSeries
                 {
                     Values = GetData(),
                     Fill = gradientBrush,
                     StrokeThickness = 0.9,
                     PointGeometry = null
                 });



        cartesianChart1.Zoom = ZoomingOptions.X; 




private ChartValues<DateTimePoint> GetData()
        {

            var values = new ChartValues<DateTimePoint>();

            for (var i = 0; i <lsTemp.Count(); i++)
            {

             // System.DateTime.Today.AddDays(i)
                values.Add(new DateTimePoint(lsDataTime[i], lsTemp[i]));
            }

            return values;
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsKrX.png)

Comment: Have you tried using ToString(FORMAT) to display your DateTime object ?

Comment: can you give an example please this is my first time i'm using c#

Answer (score 1):

you need to set LabelFormatter property of Axis class.
Something like this:

```
 AxisX = new Axis
            {
                Title = "Date",
                Separator = new Separator { IsEnabled = false,Step = 1 },
                LabelsRotation = -90,
                Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
                LabelFormatter = value =>  new System.DateTime((long)value).ToString("t")

        };
```

And look at this link for formats [ToString data formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.DateTime.ToString);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue)